# FreeTDS TSQL not working with freetds.conf

Tags: t-sql, freetds

I am using freetds version 1.00.91 from HomeBrew. I can successfully connect when I bypass the `freetds.conf`, e.g. using the following command

```
tsql -H {my_hostname} -p {port_no} -U {username} -P {password}
```

However, when I tried to

```
tsql -S MYMSSERVER -U {username} -P {password}
```

it failed with the following error:

> Msg 40532 (severity 20, state 1) from MYSERVER:
>   Cannot open server "MYSERVER" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Error 20002 (severity 9):
>   Adaptive Server connection failed
>   There was a problem connecting to the server

The `freetds.conf` content is the following:

```
[MYSERVER]
        host = {my_hostname}
        port = {port_no}
        tds version = 7.3
```

I checked the output of `tsql -C` and confirmed that 7.3 is also the version used by the `-H -p` command.

Here's some relevant info from `freetds.log` file about this error:

```
15:49:43.391174 3380 (token.c:313):looking for login token, got  aa(ERROR)
15:49:43.391215 3380 (token.c:132):tds_process_default_tokens() marker is aa(ERROR)
15:49:43.391240 3380 (mem.c:653):tds_free_all_results()
15:49:43.391258 3380 (token.c:2384):tds_process_info() reading message 40532 from server
15:49:43.391308 3380 (token.c:2456):tds_process_info() calling client msg handler
15:49:43.391391 3380 (token.c:2473):tds_process_info() returning TDS_SUCCESS
15:49:43.391418 3380 (token.c:313):looking for login token, got  fd(DONE)
15:49:43.391442 3380 (token.c:132):tds_process_default_tokens() marker is fd(DONE)
15:49:43.391471 3380 (token.c:2082):tds_process_end: more_results = 0
```

Thanks for all that help!

Comment: When you type `tsql -C`, does the `freetds.conf directory` match the location you have `freetds.conf`?

Comment: @FlipperPA yes. it does match

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, more specifically made it work with unixODBC ultimately in a hacky way.

Here's my freetds.conf file

```
[my_hostname]
        host = {my_hostname}
        port = {port_no}
        tds version = 7.3
```

And the following is my `odbc.ini` file

```
[Foo]
Description         = Test to SQLServer
Driver              = FreeTDS
Servername          = {the_same_my_hostname_as_in_freetds.conf}
Database            = BingMigration
```

`isql Foo {username} {password}` then works like a charm.

**Why it works:**

According to the [tsql man](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/confirminstall.htm#TSQL), the tsql will treat the `-S` value as hostname if no servername is found in `freetds.conf`. That's the reason why the above `freetds.conf` works. I need to name the freetds.conf section using the `my_hostname` because the `isql` seems to require a DSN that matches a section in freetds.conf in its 1st argument. Simply using a hostname that does not have corresponding section in freetds.conf failed when I tried.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of confusion here. tsql use libTDS directly, so freetds.conf while isql is a ODBC program, mainly uses odbc.ini (on Windows this is stored as registry entries). isql does not require a section name, the terminology is a DSN name.
There's no server_url, the name is usually an host name, like a DNS name.
An environment which can be useful for debugging these issue is `TDSDUMPCONFIG`.
The freetds.conf in the initial question seems correct, the fact that server return an `aa` message (`ERROR`) seems to indicate there has been a TCP connection.
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-error-messages error `40532` is `Cannot open server "%.*ls" requested by the login. The login failed`.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed some terminologies and hope that has clarified the confusion!